# Move object alongside a spherical path with fixed distance from another object

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

im having a bit of a problem and i need some help. I have a sphere object and i want to move an airplane around it. The plane is always on a fixed
distance from sphere center and i want to be able to move it freely forward, backward, left and right.

In a way the movement is two directional but since its moving around a spherical object all thre coordinates need to change. So far i have managed to get it
to move using spherical coordinates but its not working well. Since im using angles to move the play it looks and feels like with one angle im setting the
tile orbit of the plane and then i move forward / backward on that circle   .

Here is my function where i adjust the spherical coordinates

```
function moveShipInCircle(ship, movement) {
  const playerSpeed = 0.1;
  const TEMP_RAD = EARTH_RADIUS + 0.2;
  const TEMP_CAM_RADIUS = TEMP_RAD + 0.2;
  const radian = movement.firstAngle * Math.PI / 180;
  const elevation = movement.secondAngle * Math.PI / 180;
  const x = TEMP_RAD * Math.cos(radian);
  const y = TEMP_RAD * Math.sin(radian) * Math.sin(elevation);
  const z = TEMP_RAD * Math.sin(radian) * Math.cos(elevation);
  const xC = TEMP_CAM_RADIUS * Math.cos(radian);
  const yC = TEMP_CAM_RADIUS * Math.sin(radian) * Math.sin(elevation);
  const zC = TEMP_CAM_RADIUS * Math.sin(radian) * Math.cos(elevation);
  if (movement.left) {
    movement.firstAngle += playerSpeed;
  }
  if (movement.right) {
    movement.firstAngle -= playerSpeed;
  }
  if (movement.forward) {
    movement.secondAngle -= playerSpeed;
  }
  if (movement.backward) {
    movement.secondAngle += playerSpeed;
  }
  unit.position.set(x, y, z);

  camera.position.lerp(ship.position, 1.3);
  camera.position.set(xC, yC, zC);
}
```

What is the better approach to solve this?  I was thinking of "unwrapping" the sphere into a 2d plane  doing the movement there and then wrapping it up again on the sphere but that seems like im introducing unnecessary complexity. Also is hard to code on a tablet with remote pc access so im not experimenting too much  .
Thanks for any input

Comment: Are you trying to turn the plane as well, or just move it around? Because it would be pretty trivial to keep a Vector3 and change its latitude/longitude based on `sin`/`cos`. If you're trying to turn the plane so it travels in the direction of movement, that's a slightly more complex operation.

Comment: I need to turn it :)